# Git command to get a list of branches of a matching criteria

Tags: git

`git branch -r --merged master` will show you all remote repositories merged into master.

`git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' --sort=committerdate` lists the remote Git branches by author sorted by committer date. Executed in the master repo .

I would like kind of combine both, and **get all the remote branches merged to a specific branch for an specific branch creator (author)**?

Same question reformulated just in case, I want to get al the branches created by an specific developer that are merged to the main branch (master in the example), so that I can get to know the branches that can be deleted, because they're merged already.

Comment: I suspect you know this, but just in case: both "author" and "has been merged to a particular branch" are both attributes of individual *commits*, never branches. "git branch --merged" is answering the question "if I asked to merge from X into Y, would the list of commits to apply be empty?" The commits you think of as "on the branch" are the commits which _would have been_ included, had you asked at some previous point in time; but now they're merged, they're all part of the same history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two extra elements on `git for-each-ref` :

- you can list remote branches by providing the correct reference pattern :

  ```
  # this will only list remote branches :
  git for-each-ref [options] refs/remotes/origin
  ```
- `git for-each-ref` also has the [`--merged` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---mergedltobjectgt) :

> `--merged[=<object>]`
> Only list refs whose tips are reachable from the specified commit (`HEAD` if not specified).

---

Additionally, if you want to output `origin/master` instead of `refs/remotes/origin/master`, use `%(refname:short)` in the format spec :

```
git for-each-ref \
    --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname:short)'\
    --sort=committerdate --merged=master refs/remotes/origin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got to log all the branches with the creator, but how can I log only the ones created by a determined author?

Comment: I tried to fit the `--merged` in diferent places in the command like this: `git for-each-ref --merged --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' --sort=committerdate` and didnt work. I am not familiar with bash scripting

Comment: "created by a determined author" : is it ok to only look at the author of the last commit made on that branch ?

Comment: the last commit is the merge commit, is it? (sorry if the question is obvious). This would not be useful for me. I would need the branch creator, so the first commit of the branch will make much more sense

Comment: the last commit seems to be the one previous to the merge. At least that is the one provided in the command for the different branches. That is fine for me. It needs to be "a" commit from the branch, preferably the first, but as long as it is not the merge commit it is fine. That is because the developer working in the branch is not necessarily the one making the merge to the main/master branch

Comment: On the other hand the `refs/remotes/origin` at the end, is to log only the branch that do still exist remotely right? Meaning that they are not deleted in the origin

Comment: You would have to look at how your branches are merged : using PRs in github/azure devops/gitlab generally leave the original branch where it was. My question about the author was more : do  you need to search for the *first* commit on the branch ? or is the last commit on the branch ok ? (your `for-each-ref ...` will mention the author of the last commit on the branch)

Comment: last commit on the branch is fine, but if there is any other command that provides the first, I would be glad to know. My last real need is to filter the output of `git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname:short)' --sort=authorname --merged=refs/remotes/origin/master` for a determined `authorname`

Comment: I can get the branches of interest from the whole log list, but only the records of interest by an specific author would be a pro tier git command :)

Comment: although I could not achieve the query by the specific commiter the result is good enough to move on, so I accept the answer. Thanks a lot for your help :)